# Interaction with a shared network drive from within Sharepoint

Tags: integration, user-experience, network-drive

Our users generate 2 to 10 GB per project site per year, so we would like to make a distinction between "archived documents" on a network (e.g. Novell) drive, and documents that are actively worked on or shared, which are to be stored in Sharepoint 2013.

Can you recommend a way that integrates these two storage paradigms within one Sharepoint user interface?

For example: would it be possible to expose everything to search, and also embed a network file storage browser in a web part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easy but try this one

[Displaying a file or a folder in the Page Viewer Web Part](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2007/11/29/displaying-a-file-or-a-folder-in-the-page-viewer.aspx)
also check [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e2a0d9fc-0877-485d-b0a7-05bdbacb0e93/browse-network-shared-drive-files-in-sharepoint-2010-web-part-?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

For search, you can search network shared drive data from SharePoint.

check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a00b42b8-09ed-4707-898e-509cd9a271b1/shared-drive-search-from-sharepoint?forum=sharepointadminprevious)